# Cannot connect to Google Compute instance through SSH with cloud console or terminal. Filesystem failure?

Tags: google-compute-engine

My problem is:

- I can't connect through the Google Developers Console
- I can't connect with the gcloud tool
- I can't even connect to a cloned instance
- All HTTP and FTP services are running as usual but I can't upload through FTP (`error while writing: failure`)

The serial console output has a lot of entries similar to:

```
[4103217.738612] EXT4-fs error (device dm-6): htree_dirblock_to_tree:913: inode #393993: block 1587320: comm updatedb.mlocat: bad entry in directory: rec_len is smaller than minimal - offset=0(24694784), inode=0, rec_len=0, name_len=0
```

And

```
[4133580.655572] loop: Write error at byte offset 979968000, length 4096.
```

What might have happened?

Comment: You could SSH to this VM instance before or it's a newly created instance?

Comment: Yes, I could. I have a few Docker instances (web services) on the instance which is running fine.

Comment: The disk was full. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

The disk was (thankfully) full and not corrupt. I came to this conclusion by creating a snapshot of the 10GB disk, and then a new 50% larger disk from this snapshot. I attached the disk to a new instance and tried to SSH login which worked. There I could inspect the file system and saw that the disk was filled with 10GB of Docker log files.

**Solution:** I created a snapshot of the disk, created a new larger disk, a new instance and attached the new disk and old IP to the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Although you found the cause of the issue, I'd like to share the link below in case of other people face with similar issues:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors